# jsoup html parser selecting wrong table

Tags: mysql, jsoup

i need to parse http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html to get the data from the first table("platform versions") into my mysql db.
unfortunatly my program selects the last table and writes its data into the db.
actually it should hold alle elements tagged with "table" and select the first of this 3...any suggestions what went wrong? couldn't find any solution on stack yet

regards, olli

```
    ArrayList<Table>tableList = new ArrayList<Table>();

    String URL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crawler";
    String USER = "root";
    String PASSWORD = "";
    String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        //Connect to MySQL database
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
        URL url = new URL("http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html");
        //Connect to URL
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);


        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8", "http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html");
        Elements allTables = doc.getElementsByTag("table"); //hold all tables
        Element table = allTables.get(0); // using first table
        Elements row = table.getElementsByTag("tr"); //each row
        for (Element link:row){
            Elements cell = link.getElementsByTag("td"); // each cell per row

            int count =0;
            Table table1 = new Table();
            for(Element link1:cell){
                String linkText=link1.text(); //each cell value
                if(count == 0){
                    table1.setVersion(linkText);
                }else if (count == 1){
                    table1.setCodename(linkText);
                }else if(count == 2){
                    table1.setApi(Integer.parseInt(linkText));
                }else if (count == 3){
                    table1.setDistribution(Float.parseFloat(linkText));
                }
                count++;
            }
            if(count !=0){
                tableList.add(table1);
            }
        }

        for (Table table1:tableList){
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO verteilung_android2 (Version, Codename, API, Distribution) "
                    + "VALUES ('" +table1.getVersion()+ "','" +table1.getCodename()+ "','"+table1.getApi()+"','" +table1.getDistribution()+"')");
            System.out.println(tableList);
        }

    }           
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the information you want is not a table it is a java script code of a chart like this:

```
<script>
var VERSION_DATA =
[
  {
    "chart": "//chart.googleapis.com/chart?chl=Froyo%7CGingerbread%7CIce%20Cream%20Sandwich%7CJelly%20Bean%7CKitKat&chf=bg%2Cs%2C00000000&chd=t%3A0.8%2C14.9%2C12.3%2C58.4%2C13.6&chco=c4df9b%2C6fad0c&cht=p&chs=500x250",
    "data": [
      {
        "api": 8,
        "name": "Froyo",
        "perc": "0.8"
      },
      {
        "api": 10,
        "name": "Gingerbread",
        "perc": "14.9"
      },
      {
        "api": 15,
        "name": "Ice Cream Sandwich",
        "perc": "12.3"
      },
      {
        "api": 16,
        "name": "Jelly Bean",
        "perc": "29.0"
      },
      {
        "api": 17,
        "name": "Jelly Bean",
        "perc": "19.1"
      },
      {
        "api": 18,
        "name": "Jelly Bean",
        "perc": "10.3"
      },
      {
        "api": 19,
        "name": "KitKat",
        "perc": "13.6"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Jsoup cannot parse a javascript code, but you can manually parse this code.
You can do something like this, it is not do what you want but it will give you a idea to start.

```
Element script = doc.select("script").get(7); // Get the script part for chart.
            String scriptText = script.toString();
            String lines[] = scriptText.split("\\r?\\n"); //thiw will split the String line by line

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                String line = lines[i];
                if(line.contains("api"))
                    System.out.println(line);
                if(line.contains("name"))
                    System.out.println(line);
                if(line.contains("perc"))
                    System.out.println(line);
            }
```

Maybe, on the internet there is a library to parse a javascript code. But i don't know about this.